# Russian keyboard vanishes each time my Mac is started

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac-mini, language

I'm using `El Capitan` on my Mac Mini now but it started when I used `Yosemite`. I need both English and Russian keyboard layouts on my Mac. However at some point I started finding Russian layout missing once Mac is launched, so I have to go to the settings and add Russian again every time my Mac starts. Did anybody encounter a keyboard vanishing from the system constantly? What makes it dissapear every time Mac is shut down? Ayn ideas how to fix that?

Comment: By "language" you mean the keyboard/input source, right?  Your OS interface is English?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. No, my OS is Russian. Is it the case?

Comment: Did you set Russian as your primary keyboard when you first set up your Mac?

Comment: Try going to system prefs/keyboard/input sources and adding some other keyboards besides US and Russian, such as French and German.  Do they all disappear when you restart?

Comment: my primary keyboard was English. I also tried adding German, it vanishes as well, along with Russian. my Mac loves English only. Can't stand other languages

Comment: Try setting up a new user account and see if you have the same problem when logged into that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences -> Language & Region.
Set English as Preferred language. Unfortunately, your macOS becomes English, but it's the only way that solved this problem on my Sierra 10.12.5.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`, `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`, or `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*.plist`.